# nginx keeps redirecting to ip instead of subdomain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, google-compute-engine

My nginx configuration is as follows (which I meanly copied from https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#General_WordPress_rules)

```
    # HTTP server
upstream php {
        server unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name [sub.domain.com];
        #return 301 http://[sub.domain.com]$request_uri;
        ## Your only path reference.
        root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html;
        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }


        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break w$
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

}
```

I also added the following DNS record:
[image]

But if I enter [sub.domain.com] in my browser, I still get redirected to IPADDRESS. What's wrong in my .conf?

I'm using the Google Cloud Compute Engine as host.

Comment: Have you set the [WordPress HOME and SITEURL parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) correctly?

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thanks!